# receive routing error upon submitting comment form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes, controller

From the posts#show view comments can only be added if the first comment has already been created, otherwise it throws this routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :view=>"comments"}
```

Terminal reads:

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-17 18:18:03 -0700
  Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BPeNvVJh+dLBhpiZK16phQHp7UV4MasPyQW6PL9VG8I=", "comment"=>{"post_id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"", "name"=>"", "content"=>"yo"}, "commit"=>"Reply"}
AREL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("name", "content", "post_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "ancestry") VALUES ('', 'yo', NULL, '2011-05-18 01:18:03.445466', '2011-05-18 01:18:03.445466', NULL)
Completed   in 133ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :view=>"comments"}):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

If the first comment for a post is already created

posts#show:

```
<%= render @post %>

<%= nested_comments @comments.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>

<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for :comment, :url => { :controller => :comments, :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :post_id, :required => false, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :parent_id, :required => false, :as => :hidden %>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => false, :placeholder => "Name (optional)", :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :content, :label => false, :placeholder => "Reply", :as => :text %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

comments controller:

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id], :post_id => params[:post_id])
end

def create
  @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
  @comment.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      if @comment.errors.present?
        render :new
      else
        redirect_to(post_path(@comment.post, :view => "comments"))
      end
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

routes:

```
root :to => "posts#index"
resources :topics
resources :posts
resources :comments
```

schema:

```
create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "ancestry"
end

add_index "comments", ["ancestry"], :name => "index_comments_on_ancestry"

create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "topics", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but try replacing

```
redirect_to(post_path(@comment.post, :view => "comments"))
```

in your controller's create action with:

```
redirect_to(post_path(:id => @comment.post_id, :view => "comments"))
```

If the above doesn't work, we'll try something else. That seems to be the location of your problem, in any case.

Comment: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil, :view=>"comments"}):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'`

Comment: @BasicObject - you don't have an `post_id`, and this isn't even being passed into the create action. Is it possible you ran this test without any params[:post_id] at all when you entered the `new` action? I'd suggest you ensure you have your post_id set on @comment before you try to save and redirect, otherwise you'll leave yourself open to errors in the future if those post_id params ever fail to exist.

Comment: So in the create action of my controller, should I have something similar to `@comment` in the new action? `@comment = Comment.create(:parent_id => params[:parent_id], :post_id => params[:post_id])` ? I haven't been home yet to try it.

Comment: @BasicObject - your create action seems OK to me. Rather than that, your `new` action isn't actually passing `post_id` info to create in the first place. (I find this by looking at your terminal, under `POST`, under parameters, where `post_id = ""`). Make sure you're passing a post_id into your create action.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form isn't being tied to an actual comment since it's just being passed a symbol. Try this is your view

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment, :url => { :controller => :comments, :action => "create" } do |f| %>
...
```

Actually that should allow you to ditch the `:url` parameter as well

```
<%= simple_form_for @comment do |f| %>
```

Then just makes sure you define `@comment` in your controller and set the `post_id`

```
@comment = Comment.new
@comment.post_id = @post.id
```

Comment: this doesn't directly address the OP's issue. The error, particularly the terminal readout, shows that the data is being submitted successfully to the `create` action - it's having trouble redirecting _after_ that save has occurred.

Comment: It looks to me like the `post_id` and `parent_id` aren't being passed through the parameters: `"comment"=>{"post_id"=>"", "parent_id"=>"", "name"=>"", "content"=>"yo"}` which should be why it's not able to redirect to the post.

Comment: you're right about that... possibly the OP didn't have `params[:post_id]` when s/he entered the new action?